# Pything threading, how can I make 3 threads read a csv file

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, row

how can I make 3 threads read a csv file but there is an issue I can not figure out, for example on this list:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I make the threads read it like this:

```
thread 1: 1
thread 2: 2
thread 3: 3
thread 1: 4
thread 2: 5
thread 3: 6
```

I want them to keep going, what is happening right now is this:

```
thread 1: 1
thread 1: 2
thread 1: 3
thread 1: 4
thread 1: 5
thread 1: 6

thread 2: 1
thread 2: 2
thread 2: 3
thread 2: 4
thread 2: 5
thread 2: 6
etc...
```

I want them to read it row by row together, can you guys give me a hand?

This is my code, I am trying to figure out how to do the explanation above, you guys have any ideas?

```
import threading
import csv

# Function to read and print rows from the CSV file
def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(f"Thread {threading.current_thread().name} - CSV Row: {row}")

# Specify the CSV file
csv_filename = 'your_csv_file.csv'

# Create and start three threads
threads = []
for i in range(3):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=read_csv, args=(csv_filename,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply wouldn't do it that way – that file is a single resource, and you'd have to pass around a token that blocks all but one thread from reading.

Instead, you would have one "IO Thread", which is in charge of reading the file, and puts read lines into the head of a queue – if you really want to "round robin" the lines as you show in your question, each "worker thread" gets one own queue, from which it reads. If there's nothing in the queue, that reading would be blocked, until the IO thread inserts a line into the queue.

Comment: Marcus is there a way you can show me how exactly? I am trying to implement what you said at the moment hopefully I can do it correctly

Comment: Marcus Müller can't I add a row counter somehow? each time the threads enter the function the row counter increases by 1? or this is not something I can do?

Comment: That's not useful - you can only read lines "forward". You don't know where the second line in a file starts before you've finished reading the first.

Comment: I see, you really made it clear thank you mate, but the problem is with the queue it somehow kills the thread work in the first place, from my understanding if I run 10 threads, only 1 thread at a time can be launched correct? and after this thread finishes the other one starts right?

Comment: It's not me that kills the benefits of having multiple threads. It's the nature of accessing a file: that's a linear operation. And only one can do it at a time. So, as said, unless you want to have N-1 thread blocked and only 1 thread working, at which point there's no advantage to having threads at all, you need to dispatch work from an IO handling thread to other threads. Your problem really lies within the fact that reading lines is inherently not possibly parallel.

Comment: this is a great solution if you want to immediately lose all advantages of multi-threading since you'll become bottlenecked by your "IO Thread", not your storage bandwidth limitations. Have a look at case number 3 in my answer to see why you can't rely on a single thread for processing large files.

Comment: @EpicCoder thanks for the note extensive answer! But the question did specifically ask for each thread processing lines in an exact ordered round robin way, not in the way you describe. And: while of course you can open the same file multiple times in a process and read it from multiple threads in parallel, that incurs a context switch on every read, whereas on modern operating systems, exchanging/synchronization between threads can be done much cheaper, if it's necessary at all (there's lockless queues). So, your approach actually doesn't fulfill requirements (text file, line length

Comment: @EpicCoder unspecified, strict ordering of round robin), as well as being at most as fast as if the program was single-threaded, (processing each line in all threads, which you do simplify multiplies the necessary IO work and the number of context switches by the number of threads. You're only done when the slowest of these is done - so you've lost all advantages of multi-threading!)

Comment: I definitely would not recommend literally doing what OP wants (distributing individual lines). distributing individual lines causes enormous overhead. I'd suggest reading a whole bunch of lines at a time, then handing that off to whatever worker thread is ready, read another bunch of lines, repeat

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yep. At best this serves to illustrate things like "how to hand of more complex tasks from a file-type input to threads to parallelize processing". One could think of, say, a large text file with JSON objects within, each of which really means a lot of (not file IO bound) work. So, the IO thread does the lexing/parsing, and the workers do whatever these jobs are (which need to be heavier than the parsing for all this to make any sense).

Answer (score -2):

It really depends on a number of conditions:

1. If every line in your file has a known number of characters (the example you provided does) you can use some basic arithmetics to figure out which bytes should be read from the file (but this doesn't work if your lines are `[8,9,10,11]` as some lines have different number of characters).
2. If the file is relatively small (<1GB) and you want to keep reading from it, you can do a single pass to figure out the byte offsets for each line and then pass those offsets to your threads to carry out reads
3. If your file is relatively big (>10GB) you can split your file into N (N being number of threads) chunks of bytes, and pass each chunk to a thread. However this is almost guaranteed to split the file somewhere in the middle of a line, so each thread needs to start looking for newline characters, put the unprocessed bytes in a queue, process the rest normally and if there is some input left at the end, they should be passed to the queue again to be dealt with later.

This might help explain what I mean better: the example you provided has 3 characters per line (assuming you use windows):

```
1\r\n
2\r\n
3\r\n
4\r\n
5\r\n
6\r\n
7\r\n
```

where \r\n are carriage return and newline characters which are invisible but these are the characters used to determine what a newline is. So we have a total of 7*3=21 bytes to process. If we want to process this using 2 threads, one of the thread gets 11 bytes and the other thread gets 10 bytes, meaning these will be the inputs to your threads:

```
Thread 1: 1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r
Thread 2: \n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n
```

Thread 1 starts looking for newline characters and passes `1\r\n` (more realistically the offsets for those bytes) to the queue since it can't be sure it's a complete line. it then processes `2\r\n3\r\n` since it can be sure these are full lines and passes the rest (`4\r`) to the queue.
Thread 2 does a similar thing: passes `\n` to the queue, processes `5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n`, and has nothing left to pass to the queue in the end.
You then need another worker thread that joins these unprocessed bytes to form complete lines and then processes those lines.

If you give a more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve and which case applies here, I can update the answer with a more complete code example.

---

I think my answer was misunderstood, so here is an updated version that actually splits the input evenly between the threads:

```
import time
import math
from threading import Thread, Lock
from os.path import getsize

filename = "test.txt"
number_of_lines = 100
number_of_threads = 5
# This is only required for thread safe printing;
# In a real worker thread you will never do this since both locking and printing decrease preformance
lock = Lock()

with open(filename , "w") as f:
    for num in range(number_of_lines):
        f.write(f"{num}\n")
        
file_size = getsize(filename) # On windows this will be number_of_lines*3 and on linux it will be *2
ceil = int(math.ceil(file_size/number_of_threads))
offsets = [0]
for i in range(number_of_threads-1):
    offsets.append((i+1)*ceil)
offsets.append(file_size)
print(f"Wrote {file_size} bytes to {filename}")
print(f"Byte offsets passed to threads: {offsets}")
print("#"*20)

#Buffer size is how many bytes will be read in each iteration,
# in reality this should multiple KBs, but I use a small number for demonstration
def worker(filename, offset, count, thread_number, lock, buffer_size=10):
    with open(filename , "rb") as f:
        f.seek(offset)
        # Read the input in buffer_size chunks
        for _ in range(count//buffer_size):
            buffer = f.read(buffer_size)
            # go through buffer and find the first new line
            # do some processing
            with lock:
                print(f"worker {thread_number} read: {buffer}")
        buffer = f.read(count%buffer_size)
        # check if you have unprocessable data in your buffer and pass it somewhere else
        with lock:
            print(f"worker {thread_number} read: {buffer}")
        
threads = [Thread(target=worker, args=(filename, offsets[i], offsets[i+1]-offsets[i], i, lock)) for i in range(number_of_threads)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I'm well aware this is extremely inefficient in practice due to:

1. Using Python is slow and if you want performance, you need to write your own C++ extensions
2. The file size and buffer sizes are so small that threading adds way too much overhead meaning that just reading the file in one go is much quicker.

Again this is not about providing a complete example, but to show that this can be done and that you're not bound to one "IO Thread" as others have suggested. Obviously reading the entire file in every thread is pointless, but you can easily use the `seek()` and `read()` functions to read a file at a given offset for a given number of bytes.

I had to use very similar tricks on a project that required only using CSV files instead of a DB to run queries on the CSV and the file sizes were a few GB. splitting the inputs like this allowed a very fast initial pass to create indices on the dataset which was later used to run the actual queries.

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for the extensive answer to complement my answer: I don't think this is what the asker needs, see my answering comments to your comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333823/pything-threading-how-can-i-make-3-threads-read-a-csv-file/77333871?noredirect=1#comment136337199_77333871).

Comment: But: I think you can at least improve the approach so that the idea becomes feasible: You're building an N=number of threads read amplification, which you shouldn't do. If, instead of the inherently quite linear line access you could use the princinples you sketched in the answer, namely letting different threads access the file at different offsets, you could get rid of the explicit `read` calls, and avoid necessarily `read`ing the same data twice (as far as buffers allow) by using `mmap` in the mother thread and accessing the single `mmap`ed file from multiple threads concurrently. That …

Comment: … would only incur a context switch on file regions you haven't read in any thread yet (&that hasn't been evicted yet, if your OS does that to mmap'ed files under memory pressure). It doesn't work well when multiple threads try to access the same region for the first time in short time – you get a page fault for as long as the OS hasn't *finished* doing the IO yet. Essentially: having to mediate concurrent access to the same data is a losing game, no matter whether your program or OS does it, which is why "defaulting" to an IO thread is usually not a bad choice, for performance and complexity.

Comment: I can't find a strict requirement on round robin (which is still doable, just less efficient with more context-switching). The example code provided was to also demonstrate the fact that you can concurrently read from a file, not a useful piece of code or particularly efficient. You are correct that the whole file can be memory mapped and the map can be passed to threads but that requires a lot more code and I don't see why it should cause issues. The entire point I made was threads access strictly different regions of the input at the same time.

Comment: Again, the issue you can't see here is critical, especially when you accuse my solution of losing all benefits of multi-threading: your approach is causing N times the `read` calls, which means your program needs to yield control to the operating system N times as often as a single-threaded application, or one with an IO thread, and more specifically, N times more often than you'd need to get the data from the file system into your application. That is exactly what you *not* want if you branch out work on data to multiple threads – not only are such context switches really expensive,

Comment: you also start lying to yourself that you've just solved the access contention problem. Now it's just the operating system having to arrange your concurrent accesses. That's the thing: One storage! It's no better than you at that; and all multiple-queue read devices on higher end storage systems included, nothing is faster than reading linearly from any storage device and prefetching as much as possible to keep the storage bus occupied with useful (unique!) accesses the whole time. You literally found the way to make N threads not be faster than a single-threaded application :)

Comment: The OS doesn't prevent multiple threads from reading the same source, as long as the file handle is different, there is no locking mechanism in place to prevent this. Why do you think tools like text editors create previews and copies of what they do and compare it with the actual data on disk? it's required so modifications from other sources don't cause incorrect file edits, instead, they create warnings about other modifications. For larger files, this approach will be faster than using a single pre-fetch thread. If the files were locked for reading, things like a NAS would crawl to a halt.

Comment: You're right that the OS doesn't prevent you from doing that, and I never claimed that, but don't ignore what happens inside the OS! The OS still can't magically read multiple different blocks from a disk in parallel. It still needs to make sure that physically accessing the storage happens in a coordinated way. You're really acting as if your OS wasn't running on the same CPU cores as your program, but it is, and now you've just shifted the effort of keeping multiple accesses detangled from your application to the OS.

Comment: I did mention that when files are small this doesn't make sense. Even Python's official doc admits this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html. but for LARGE files (again, more than 1GB) the threads will be accessing completely different storage blocks, meaning the storage bandwidth IS used. Just look for any number of multi-threaded file copy utilities out there, why do you think they're there? you can also check disk benchmarking utilities that expose threading options.

Comment: Unless you're talking about hard drives that have horrible random IO performance, but that's a different topic altogether. The OS just queues the reads and loads the data into memory. Each thread can queue its own reads and if you have an SSD (or ram disk, or similar) that does allow decent random access, there is no blocking happening.

Comment: I'm writing a lot on very heavily multi-threaded software, @EpicCoder. It's not just "look at these examples that others wrote" for me ;) I've battled the problems of concurrent access to IO quite a bit. So, the thing is that I just explained how you can, for the mostly non-overlapping case, reduce your read amplification problem. And then I explained that "just queues the reads in memory" is *really* just acting as if it costs nothing that the OS does that. But it does. And the OS can't know your access pattern, but your application does.

Comment: please learn about how storage is accessed. it's not individual byte reads. it's an entire block per read. sectors, clusters, several of those, whatever. such fine interleaving of reads will kill performance trivially. at best, the OS will hide it with caching. please take a step back and consider how much you really know about the topics you're answering.

Comment: the best solution is to have _one_ thread read the file. that's basically IO bound. OP's desire to multithread in this fashion is misguided and should be discouraged at all costs. such a file may be split into chunks of lines for multiprocessing. distributing single lines is the worst possible solution (unless you get creative and find something even worse). always remember, coordination has a cost. the less coordination, the better. large chunks are cheaper than small chunks.

Comment: reading the file in multiple passes is also a bad idea. it's utterly wasteful. you'd have the data in RAM already at the first pass. it makes no sense to gather "offsets" and then read  the handful of bytes for each line, from multiple threads, in any kind of interleaving.

Comment: I take it that you did not read the answer and just rushed to comment. I specifically added a comment about needing to read multiple KBs on each read : `in reality this should multiple KBs, but I use a small number for demonstration` . My solution doesn't interleave the lines, just splits a large file evenly between N threads. Each thread will have SEQUENTIAL reads but the overall program will have RANDOM reads on NON OVERLAPPING parts of the disk.

Comment: @EpicCoder your comment again ignores about a dozen comments that people more experienced in the matter have given you. I'm afraid arguing with you makes no sense here, and so, I'll just leave it at that. **This is my last reply to you.**